# Filter latest records of HasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am struggling to figure out how I can get `Doctor::latestPatientProtocols` returning the relationship instead the collection. I have commented out what did not work for me.

Doctor -> `hasMany` Patient -> `hasMany` -> PatientProtocol

But only the latest protocol is valid on the patient. How can I get the latest PatientProtocol starting the query from the Doctor and returning the Builder instead of the Collection?

```php
<?php

class Doctor extends BaseModel
{
    public function patients(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Patient::class);
    }

    public function latestPatientProtocols(): Collection
    {
        return $this->patients->map(fn (Patient $patients) => $patients->latestPatientProtocols)->filter();
    }

//    public function latestPatientProtocols(): HasManyThrough
//    {
//        return $this->hasManyThrough(
//            PatientProtocol::class,
//            Patient::class)
//            ->selectRaw(
//                'patient_protocols.*, MAX(patient_protocols.created_at) as latest_created_at'
//            )->groupBy('patient_protocols.id');
//    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Patient extends BaseModel
{
    public function doctor(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Doctor::class);
    }

    public function latestPatientProtocol(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PatientProtocol::class)
            ->latestOfMany('created_at');
    }

    public function patientProtocols(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PatientProtocol::class);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class PatientProtocol extends Model
{
    public function patient(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
    }
}
```